# Как задать класс стиля в компоненте PrimeNG?

Tags: css3, angularjs, typescript

Всем доброго дня! Появилась необходимость задать стиль классом в компоненте PrimeNG. На первый взгляд простая задача, но стилизация компонента только в документации явно через указание inline стиля. Компонент переписывать не вижу резона ради этого. Часть View из Angular компонента

```
<style>
.data {
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="mdl_" (keypress)="onKey($event)" 
[style]="'font-weight':'bold'"/>
```

Так, как привел код, не хочу. Надо задействовать класс data. Как его указать в style? Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно не понял вопроса, но что мешает явно указать класс

```
<input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="mdl_" (keypress)="onKey($event)" class="data"/>
```

Если же есть некое условие при котором нужно выбрать из нескольких классов, то используйте директиву `[class.{name of css class}]`

```
<input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="mdl_" (keypress)="onKey($event)" [class.data]="someCondition"/>
```

Comment: мешает viewEncapsulation

Answer (score 2):

Стили любого компонента по умолчанию будут иметь постфикс вида `_ngcontent-${id}`.  Он добавляется в случае `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` в декораторе `Component`. Стили же для компонентов PrimeNg указаны как `body .component-class { ... }`. Это ответ на то, почему с классами не работает - веса селекторов(постфиксный вариант "тяжелее").

Есть несколько вариантов-workaround:

1. Использовать специальный селектор `::ng-deep`(>4.3.0) или `/deep/`/`>>>`(<4.2.6)
2. Выставить `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`. Можно будет "стилить" классами, но в ущерб инкапсуляции компонента. Не советовал бы в случае среднего/большого проектов.
3. Переназначать стили PrimeNg в файле `style.css`(в случае c angular-cli). Минус в том, что перебивать стили напрямую - bad practice, может привести к своеобразным багам и подорожанию поддержки. Положительный эффект можно наблюдать только в случае использования html/css фреймворка(bootstrap, foundation, bulma etc.), когда нужно унифицировать компоненты(кнопки, поля ввода)
4. Заметил недавно в документации к angular-material совет, добавлять ссылку к стилю vendor-компонента в массив `styleUrls`, что позволит все держать и редактировать в пределах компонента не в ущерб инкапсуляции и best-practices. Как понял я: такое будет работать  только в случае модульности библиотеки компонентов, где для каждого компонент строго свой файл стилей

Comment: Спасибо embarq за помощь. Проект близкий к среднему по масштабам, использовал вариант 3 - переопределил стили компонентов PrimeNG, не факт, что это правильно, но все же...